# Create a virtual/fake url to file content

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I've recently changed my library code to es6 using webpack, babel, and all of this family.

So my production is single file in the end.. compares to before that I had a lot of files that were being loaded dynamically by demand.

My problem is that I'm using another library that loads some of their class dynamically, and in order to customise them I need to provide URL to my custom objects/classes.
It was not a problem at first, because I had a lot of files, but now my code is bundled into a single file.

Is there a way js/es6/... to give some content/string and create a fake url to it, so the other library will 'load' it ?

for example:

My classes are

**file ../myLib/CustomLayer2D.js**

```
Class CustomLayer2D {
...
}
```

**file ../myLib/CustomLayer3D.js**

```
Class CustomLayer3D {
...
}
```

**file ../myLib/CustomLayer.js**
*This is the use of the other library*

```
Accessor.createSubClass([layer], {

     viewModulePaths:{
        "2d": "need to provide here a url to 2d layer file",
        "3d": "need to provide here a url to 3d layer file"
     }
});
```

**file ../myLib/CustomLayer.js**

```
Class CustomLayer2D {
...
}

Class CustomLayer3D {
...
}

Accessor.createSubClass([], {

     viewModulePaths:{
        "2d": "need to provide here a path to 2d layer",
        "3d": "need to provide here a path to 3d layer"
     }
});
```

*I'd prefer finding a way and not exclude my custom classes from the bundle (my last resort).*

Comment: Not sure if it answers your question at all since I don't know nothing of webpack, so will stay in comments, but yes, you can create an url pointing to an in-memory text file from a string with web APIs : `URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(['your text goes here'], {type: 'text/plain'}));`.

Comment: This is what I've searched for!! I knew this method but somehow it slipped out of my mind.. Anyway, I used it and it worked.. So Thank you @Kaiido. I will post a full answer with webpack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @Kaiido comment and a bit of more research I've came to a full solution.

In our `webpack.config.js` we are adding our files to run through the `raw-loader` - so instead of bundling the real code it will bundle the file as it is - Text file.

In our code we simply import our file/s and put it in `<<The Code>>`

`URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([<<The Code>>], {type: 'text/plain'}));`

It looks like this

**webpack.config.js**
*under `rules` property*

```
{
    test: /myLib\\CustomLayer2D.js|myLib\\CustomLayer3D.js/,
    loader: 'raw-loader',
}
```

**file myLib/CustomLayer.js**

```
import layer2DCode from './myLib/CustomLayer2D.js'
import layer3DCode from './myLib/CustomLayer3D.js'

Accessor.createSubClass([], {

     viewModulePaths:{
        "2d": URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([layer2DCode], {type: 'text/plain'})),
        "3d": URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([layer3DCode], {type: 'text/plain'}))
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Webpack can bundle all assets in one js file, but you can still use separate js files with Webpack or Webpack-dev-server.

You can use [webpack-dev-server's config](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-contentbase) or just put your ../myLib/CustomLayer3D.js beside the webpack bundle file to dynamically load 2D or 3D.js file in you original way instead of require/import them in CustomLayer.js.

Besides what's your another library? maybe it has some other way to load a class dynamically.

Comment: Yes.. I know that (exclude from bundling), but I wished to provide single file and now i need to provide 3.. The library i'm using is esri 4 (gis engine).. They didn't provide a customising way yet, but my library does already. They are using Dojo toolkit. Anyway, i don't think i will find a solution but excluding it from the bundling.